# Use ruby gem, apt-get,etc. through a proxy with NTLM authentication

Tags: authentication, proxy, ntlm

What solutions are out there for getting through a corporate proxy using NTLM authentication? Anything that isn't a browser fails.

I've tried NTLMAPS, without success.

Answer (score 2):

[Cntlm](http://cntlm.awk.cz/) works great. Be sure to follow the "Configuration hints" section, it will save you some trial-and-error cycles.